# Problema on tkinter with pyinstaller

Tags: python, tkinter, pyinstaller

I'm having a problem converting my code to an executable with pyinstaller. It's a code that use tkfilebrowser to choose directories and print them. If you try it on python it run without major problems. But if you try to make it an executable, it doesn't work when you try to choose a directory, with the error:"_tkinter.TclError: couldn't open "C:Users...\tkfilebrowser...\file.png": no such file or directory". I will be grateful for any help. Below there's more details about the code and bug.

My simple code is the following:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkfilebrowser
root = tk.Tk()


canvas = tk.Canvas(root, height=600, width=1133, bg="black") 
canvas.pack()

frame = tk.Frame(root, bg="white")
frame.place(relwidth=0.96, relheight=0.6, relx=.02,rely=0.28)


dirs=[]
def get_directories():
    aux=[]
    aux.append(tkfilebrowser.askopendirnames(initialdir="/"))



    for i in aux[0]:
        dirs.append(i)
    print(dirs)
    return dirs

selectFolder = tk.Button(root, text= '1 - Select Folder', padx=5, pady=5, fg="white", 
bg="#263D42", command = get_directories)
selectFolder.pack(side=tk.RIGHT)

root.mainloop()
```

To take it to an executable i'm using the following command on cmd (i'm saving the file with the name "test"):

```
 pyinstaller.exe --onefile --test.py
```

You can see the error in the following image.
[image: Problem with pyinstaller]

Comment: what is `tkfilebrowser` ? It seems it may need `images/file.png` and you will have to add it to your project and to special file `.spec`  created by `PyInstaller` to inform `PyInstaller` that it has to add `images/file.png` to `.exe`

Comment: Thanks for your comment. tkfilebrowser is a package on python that allow to select more than one directory (as far as I know it is only one that allows select multiple directories). Looks like image/file.png is the think that's giving the problem how do you suggest to me proceed? I don't know how to add it to the project (on .py file it's not required).

Comment: as I said - when you runs `PyInstaller` then it should create file with extension `.spec` and you should add infromation to this file. Read documentation: [Using Spec Files](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/spec-files.html). I found source code for `tkfilebrowser` and it has folder `images` with different images for `tkfilebrowser`. You should add paths for all images to `.spec`

Comment: Yes, it has a spec file, but I don't know how to add information on it or how to add paths for all images to .spec. Could you help me on that?

Comment: read documentation: [Using Spec FIles](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/spec-files.html)

Comment: Ok, thank you. I will try it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that pyinstaller is not importing the tkfilebrowser module. You should import manually.
Please add the path to your tkfilebrowser folder in the spec file with the following code:

```
# test.spec file
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
         cipher=block_cipher)            
a.datas += Tree("C:\\Users\\I_like_chocolate\\Miniconda3\\Lib\\site- 
packages\\tkfilebrowser\\", "tkfilebrowser") # !!! Path to add
```

Be sure to **save** the test.spec file before running again. Then, instead of runing the `pyinstaller.exe --onefile --test.py` comand you should run the test.spec file in the cmd with the comand:

```
# cmd
pyinstaller.exe test.spec
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I found the path to tkfilebrowser, it is inside the folder .config, but where should I run the code you sent to me? I tried on cmd and as a python code.

Comment: @ChibiPeew in the cmd. Try to run the comdan pyinstaller.exe test.spec or pyinstaller test.spec. Be sure that the test.spec fil have the modifications saved.

Answer (score 0):

I think this way is a lot easier:

```
import os
import sys

def resource_path(relative_path):
    try:
        base_path = sys._MEIPASS # after running the pyinstaller, if still looking
        # for temp folder then use sys._MEIPASS2 and if needed \\ instead of / for
        # all the path directories
    except Exception:
        base_path = os.path.abspath(".")

    return os.path.join(base_path, relative_path)
```

Replace the

```
"folder_names/file_names"
```

with

```
resource_path("file_names/file_names")
```

in the Terminal type:

```
pyinstaller.exe --onefile --windowed  --icon=your_image.ico Your_File.py
```

or
in windows CMD (after installing the pyinstaller in cmd) type:

```
pyinstaller --onefile --windowed --icon=your_image.ico Your_File.py
```

The executable file will be available in a new folder called "dist".

now copy all the dependent folders into the "dist" folder

run the .exe and if all fine then zip the folder to share.

Delete Build and Dist folder along with any .spec files.

Replace the

```
resource_path("folder_names/file_names")
```

back to

```
"folder_names/file_names"
```

If file not found error:
Use MEIPASS instead of MEIPASS2 or vise versa and then \ instead of / if needed.

To go one step further and turn it into a setup installer file, use "inno setup" software.